# Reference unmanaged assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, assemblies

I'm trying to reference a managed DLL in my .NET project, without copying it into my output directory. So, when my program runs, it runs the DLL from the location it's installed - wherever that is. The problem lies in the fact that this managed DLL calls unmanaged DLLs. When I try and reference the managed DLL, it throws a `FileNotFound Exception - Could not load  file or assembly 'CharacterGen' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find file specified`. When I set my output to be within the same directory as the DLL I'm referencing, everything works fine. The usual solution would be to also reference the DLLs which are called from within the other assembly. However, I can't reference unmanaged assemblies from my managed program.

Is there a way to reference a managed DLL which calls unmanaged DLLs?

Comment: Are you familiar with GAC..? if you do not want to copy into the bin folder then create a separate folder but you will still need to copy the .dll's to that folder, refernce them ect.. if not you will have to do some LoadFromAssebly code using search paths why would you not want to just copy the .dll's to a location that can be referenced properly.. also haave you thought about creating a MSI installer that way if the user wants to run your application / set it up in a different directory structure.. at least they can do that and the related reference dependencies will be handled..

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GAC but from what I understand, assemblies have to be signed. I don't have control over the DLLs I'm referencing so I can't verify if they're signed or not. I thought about an installer, but I don't want to install into the user's existing directory because it's not my program's directory, it's one that exists on my client's machines. That will have to be my fallback if nothing else works.

Comment: The GAC is not useful for referencing unmanaged DLLs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you asking how to get visual studio to copy the unmanaged DLL to your output directory you can do this:

1. Add the unmanaged dll as a file or linked file in your project.  (right click project -> add -> existing file then either Add or Add as Link).
2. Select the file in the solution explorer.  In the properties window set build action to copy always.

Comment: Don't forget that the unmanaged DLL could itself require other unmanaged DLL's.  If you forget to add those as well, you could get the exact same error.  You can use dependency walker to help you if you are not sure what the dependencies are.

Comment: Thanks! Just to correct you, Copy Always isn't under "Build Action", it's under "Copy to Output Directory"

Answer (score 2):

If your solution has a bunch of unmanaged C++ dlls that you're building and one or two managed C# assemblies, and they all need to be in the same folder, I've found that setting all of the projects to use the same output directory to be the easiest to manage solution. -- This way, if projects get renamed later, etc., they all still end up in the right location, and if you add a new project later, you don't have to figure out what dlls need to be added in, you just need to set the `OutputPath` to the exact same thing as your other projects.

To achieve this I set the `OutputPath` property (for all Configurations and Platforms, for every project) to `$(SolutionDir)\bin\$(Configuration)`.

Generally, I don't include `$(Platform)` in the path, because for the unmanaged projects it's named `Win32` and for the managed it's named `x86` -- but if you really need platform segregation you can do some conditional logic in the .csproj files to create a new property that has the desired value.